# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Database. How to fix?

Tags: php, mysql

I've seen the question asked but the answer wasn't very clear to me.
My code is.

index.php

```
 <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
    <?php
      include "class.users.php";
      if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username1'];
        $password = $_POST['password1'];
        $users->login($username, $password);
      }
    ?>
```

class.users.php

```
<?php
  include "connect.php";
  class Users extends Database {
    public function login($username, $password) {
      $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1");
      $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
      $stmt->store_result();
      if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        while($stmt->fetch()) {
          $_SESSION['username'] == $username;
          header("Location: dashboard.php");
        }
      } else {
          return false;
      }
      $stmt->close();
      $stmt->free_result();
    }
  }
  $users = new users();
?>
```

connect.php

```
<?php

    class Database {
      public function __construct() {
        $host = 'localhost';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = '';
        $name = 'meeboo3';
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $name);
      }
    }
    ?>
```

The class Database isn't called twice? so how is it a error? can anyone explain why in the comments.

Comment: what's in `connect.php`?

Comment: I wonder if class Database is already declared or included in header.php or connect.php?

Comment: sorry i forgot the add in connect.php

Comment: yeah its included with header.php is that the problem??

Answer (score 1):

you could test to see if its already declared before doing so:

```
if (!isset($database) && !is_a($database, 'Database')){
  $database = new Database();
}
```

Or

if you're declaring it inside  `connect.php` you could:

```
include_once 'connect.php';
```

instead of

```
include 'connect.php';
```